# Make parallel http requests using raw data files

Tags: shell, command-line, curl, gnu-parallel

I've several files containg POST body requests.

I'd like to send those requests in parallel.

Related curl command is like:

```
curl -s -X POST $FHIR_SERVER/ -H "Content-Type: application/fhir+json" --data "@patient-bundle-01.json"
```

Request bodies are files like `patient-bundle-xx`, where `xx` is a number. Currently, I'd like to send up to 1500 requests using this incremental pattern.

1. How could I send above requests using incremental pattern?
2. How could I do this in parallel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU Parallel:

```
doit() {
  bundle="$1"
  curl -s -X POST $FHIR_SERVER/ -H "Content-Type: application/fhir+json" --data "@patient-bundle-$bundle.json"
}
export -f doit
export FHIR_SERVER
seq -w 99 | parallel -j77 doit
```

Adjust `-j77` if you do not want 77 jobs in parallel.